# Changing tag in a HTML when parsed with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a [webpage](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=144185.html) using beautiful soup but I got a problem with a tag that is mysteriously changing from what is displayed in my browser and what I receive in my terminal.
[image: This tab]

[image: Correspond to this tag]

Ok so the tab above is corresponding to the HTML tag above in my browser.
Once I parsed it with beautiful I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    
url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=144185.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
trailer = soup.find(title="Bandes-annonces")
print trailer
```

Which output:

```
<span class="ACrL3ZACrpZGVvL3BsYXllcl9nZW5fY21lZGlhPTE5NTYxOTgyJmNmaWxtPTE0NDE4NS5odG1s item trailer icon icon-play-mini" title="Bandes-annonces">
        Bandes-annonces
    </span>
```

I would like to know why my "a" tag suddenly became a "span" tag? How can I avoid it?

Comment: look at the page source.  It might be changed with javascript.  If so, try selenium to scrape the page as rendered

Comment: Probably, the tag containing 'title=bandes-announces' that is found first is span tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of issues, some tags are created using *Javascript*, there are actually two tags that have a *title="Bandes-annonces"*, what you see in your output is the first occurrence with obfuscated data which is *base-64* encoded with substring(s) embedded, you can see in one of the Js functions that has `AC.config = {`  the following:

```
 seo: {
        obfuscatedPrefix: 'ACr'
    },
```

Each tag in the source you get back from requests contains the encoded data like *ACrL3ZACrpZGVvL3BsYXllcl9nZW5fY21lZGlhPTE5NTYxOTgyJmNmaWxtPTE0NDE4NS5odG1s*

You can see if we replace any occurrences of the prefix *ACr* and *base-64* decode the remaining string:

```
In [113]: s = "ACrL3ZACrpZGVvL3BsYXllcl9nZW5fY21lZGlhPTE5NTYxOTgyJmNmaWxtPTE0NDE4NS5odG1s"

In [114]: s.replace("ACr", "").decode("base-64")
Out[114]: '/video/player_gen_cmedia=19561982&cfilm=144185.html'
```

We get the href.

If you wanted to get the tag with the title, you could use one of the *css classes*:

```
trailer = soup.find(class_="icon-play-mini", title="Bandes-annonces")
```

which if we run the code:

```
In [117]: url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=144185.html"

In [118]: page = requests.get(url)

In [119]: soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

In [120]: trailer = soup.find(class_="icon-play-mini", title="Bandes-annonces")

In [121]: print trailer
<span class="ACrL3ZACrpZGVvL3BsYXllcl9nZW5fY21lZGlhPTE5NTYxOTgyJmNmaWxtPTE0NDE4NS5odG1s item trailer icon icon-play-mini" title="Bandes-annonces">
            Bandes-annonces
        </span>
```

Gives you the second occurrence of the tag with the title=..

Then to get the href:

```
In [122]: trailer["class"][0].replace("ACr", "").decode("base-64")
Out[122]: '/video/player_gen_cmedia=19561982&cfilm=144185.html'
```

You can see it is not going to be very straight forward to scrape data from that site, the obfuscation is likely there for a good reason, to make scraping harder as they most likely don't want you to be doing it.

Comment: Actually I just want to see if the tab "bande-annonce" is is disabled or not. Like "vod"

Comment: What signifies that it is disabled.

Comment: If there is a link you can click on it or not

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, is the a disabled attribute or how exactly do you know it is disabled?

Comment: No worries just find out the solution with your answer thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've got another questions; how do you realised what kind of encoding it was? Because I've got another encoded string but it doesn't seem to be the same type: "acLnk 1FC243C14643C21F4446424543C243C146433F4C43493F42C243C146432E2C2A232C1945CB4E48"